# why footer links is not working while resizing using bootstrap?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

i have made the website mobile responsive.All are done.

This is the website which i made responsive.

```
alpha.dubaiexporters.com
```

what is happening is that when its of desktop size,the footer links are clickable but when i resize it to small screen,footer links shows unclickable.

i used the inspect element to know the issue and i found that its because of `<div class="clearfix">` . So i removed it from my coding but the problem still persists.I dont have any idea.Even i tried removing .clearfix before and after from bootstrap.cs but its not working.[[image: Here the marked part[links] is unclickable when resize.[1]]

i dont know why clearfix div is displaying even after removing it from code.

code:

```
 <div class="footer-wrapper">
                                          <div class="footer-container vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid ">
                                             <%-- <a href="http://cohhe.com/demo/sky/sky-directory" class="footer-logo-link"><img src="//cohhe.com/demo/sky/sky-directory/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/skydirectory-footer-logo.png" class="footer-logo " alt="Sky Directory" /></a>--%>
                                                  <div class="footer-content" style="padding-top:60px;">
                                                      <div class="footer-links-container columns_count_2">
                                                         <div id="first" class="widget-area footer-links  vc_col-sm-6 " role="complementary">
                                                             <div id="sky-directory-useful-links-20" class=" sky-usefullinks widget widget_sky-directory-useful-links row-fluid" style="width: 50%;float:left;">
                                                                <div class="useful-links-title">
                                                                   About DubaiExporters
                                                                </div><a href="aboutus.aspx">About Us</a><br /><a href="http://cohhe.com/demo/sky/sky-directory/contact/">Member Benefits</a><br /><a href="link_us.aspx">Link Us</a><br /><a href="media_partners.aspx">Media Partners</a><br /><a href="contactus.aspx">Contact Us</a><br /><%--<div class="clearfix"></div>--%></div><div id="sky-directory-useful-links-21" class=" sky-usefullinks widget widget_sky-directory-useful-links row-fluid" style="width: 50%;float:left;">
                                                                <div class="useful-links-title">
                                                                  Information
                                                                </div><a href="news.aspx">News</a><br /><a href="exhibition.aspx">Upcoming Exhibitions</a><br /><a href="advertize.aspx">Advertise</a><br /><a href="addexhibition.aspx">Add Your Event</a><br /><a href="#"></a><br /><%--<div class="clearfix"></div>--%></div> </div>
                                                                <div id="second" class="widget-area footer-links  vc_col-sm-6 last" role="complementary">
                                                                   <div id="sky-directory-contact-us-11" class=" sky-contactus widget widget_sky-directory-contact-us row-fluid">
                                                                       <div class="contact-us-widget-main">
                                                                           <div class="contact-us-phone">
                                                                             <span class="phone-icon fa fa-mobile"></span>
                                                                                <div class="phone-info-container">
                                                                                  <span class="phone-text">Call us:</span>
                                                                                  <span class="phone-number">+971 4 3050755</span>
                                                                                  </div>
                                                                                   <%--<div class="clearfix"></div>--%>
                                                                                   </div>
                                                                                   <div class="contact-us-lower">
                                                                                      <div class="contact-us-social"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/dubaiexportersuae" class="contact-us-facebook fa fa-facebook"></a><a href="http://twitter.com/#!/dubaiexporters" class="contact-us-twitter fa fa-twitter"></a>
                                                                                       <%--<div class="clearfix"></div>--%>
                                                                                       </div>
                                                                                      <div class="contact-us-email">
                                                                                         <a href="mailto:info@skydirectory.com" class="email-address">
                                                                                          <span class="email-text">Or send an email to:</span>info@dubaiexporters.com</a>
                                                                                      </div>
                                                                                      </div>
                                                                                      <%--<div class="clearfix"></div>--%>
                                                                                      </div>
                                                                      <%-- <div class="clearfix"></div>--%>

                                                                   </div> </div>
                                                                                      <%--<div class="clearfix"></div>--%>
                                                                                      </div>
                                                                                      </div>
                                                                                       <%--<div class="scroll-to-top-container">
                                                                                       <div class="scroll-to-top"><span>To Top</span></div>
                                                                                       </div>--%>
                                                                                       <div class="footer-inner">
                                                                                         <div class="footer_info">
                                                                                           <div class="copyright">© 2018, Dubai Exporters</div>
                                                                                             <%--<div class="clearfix"></div>--%>
                                                                                         </div>
                                                                                          </div>
                                                                                          <div class="footer-cloud-container">
                                                                                             <%--<img src="http://cohhe.com/demo/sky/sky-directory/wp-content/themes/sky/images/bottom-cloud.png" width="266" height="116" alt="Footer cloud"/>--%>
                                                                                         <%-- <div class="clearfix"></div>--%>
                                                                                          </div>
                                                                                            </div>
                                                                                            </div>
```

Comment: there is div with clearfix over your links which doesn't allow to click. add media query to its ::before and ::after and make it display:none;